# How to get the term frequency of specific term in each doc with Lucene5.3?

Tags: java, lucene

Imagine there are three documents.
Doc1: Hi everyone, I am Li. Hi.
Doc2: Well done boy. 
Doc3: Hi, boy. I am Young.

I try to get the term frequency of each term in each document with Lucene5.3.

The result I want to get:
Doc1：
Hi 2
everyone 1 
I 1 
am 1
Li 1

```
1   IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(iNDEX_DIR2).toPath()));

2   int num_doc = reader.numDocs();
3   for(int docNum=0; docNum<num_doc; docNum++){
4       try{

5           Document doc = reader.document(docNum);
6           System.out.println("Processing file:"+doc.get("filename"));
7           
8           Terms termVector = reader.getTermVector(docNum, "contents");
9           TermsEnum itr = termVector.iterator();
10          BytesRef term = null;
11                          
12          while((term = itr.next()) != null){
13              try{
14                  String termText = term.utf8ToString();
15                  Term termInstance = new Term("contents",term);      
16                  long termFreq = reader.totalTermFreq(termInstance);
17                  long docCount = reader.docFreq(termInstance);
18                  
19                  System.out.println("term: "+termText+", termFreq = "+termFreq+", docCount = "+docCount);
20              }catch(Exception e){
21                  System.out.println(e);
22              }
23          }
```

I get the total term frequency of specific term.
Could anyone to help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PostingEnum.freq()](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/PostingsEnum.html#freq%28%29%20PostingEnum.freq()).

In your case you have an index with TermVector so use the following (after line 7):

```
8           Terms termVector = reader.getTermVector(docNum, "contents");
9           TermsEnum itr = termVector.iterator();
10          BytesRef term = null;
11          PostingsEnum postings = null;
12          while((term = itr.next()) != null){
13              try{
14                  String termText = term.utf8ToString();
15                  postings = itr.postings(postings, PostingsEnum.FREQS);
16                  int freq = postings.freq();
17
18
19                  System.out.println("doc:" + docNum + ", term: " + termText + ", termFreq = " + freq);
20              } catch(Exception e){
21                  System.out.println(e);
22              }
23          }
```

(if you need the frequency for all documents: be aware that you can reach PostingEnum without TermVector).

Comment: With this piece of code, I am getting an error - `java.lang.IllegalStateException: DocsEnum not started`

Comment: @Vijendra
write `postings.nextDoc();` line 16.